# PDAL colorizing LAZ with GeoTIFF

Tags: gdal, vrt, pdal, laz

I understand the example from PDAL [workshop](https://pdal.io/workshop/exercises/analysis/colorization/colorization.html) and it works well. However since I puzzle around with some data and find most effective way to use it I thought I might ask for some opinions here.

I do have a set of some thousand orthophotos and some thousand tiles of LAZ data. The grids of each do not correspond unfortunately. I read about the approach using GNU parallel to speed things up.  I came up with some scripting to match everything together and it works well. However this mean I need to the matching first wich takes quite a time.

Then I remembered the GDAL VRT and started a try and error. My idea was to wrap all my orthophotos into a VRT and only iterate over my LAZ tiles and color it with them. But surprisingly this is not performant at all (while it is in QGIS for visualisation).

Even when I use `GDAL_MAX_DATASET_POOL_SIZE=450` and `GDAL_CACHEMAX=16000`

See results:

**1:1 orthophoto -> LAZ**

```json
{
    "pipeline": [
        "/data/result/0_repair_srs/2616500_1261000.laz",
        {
            "type": "filters.colorization",
            "raster": "/data/data/ch.swisstopo.swissimage_2022.rgb/swissimage-dop10_2021_2616-1261_0.1_2056.tif"
        },
        {
            "type": "writers.las",
            "compression": "true",
            "minor_version": "2",
            "dataformat_id": "3",
            "filename":"/data/result/1_processing_via_index/2616500_1261000.laz"
        }
    ]
}
```

```bsh
time pdal pipeline /data/result/1_processing_via_index/colorizing_pipeline.json

real    3m37.447s
user    3m36.350s
sys 0m0.530s
```

**VRT -> LAZ**

```json
{
    "pipeline": [
        "/data/result/0_repair_srs/2616500_1261000.laz",
        {
            "type": "filters.colorization",
            "raster": "/data/result/2_processing_via_vrt/2_vrt_from_orthophoto/dop_index.vrt"
        },
        {
            "type": "writers.las",
            "compression": "true",
            "minor_version": "2",
            "dataformat_id": "3",
            "filename":"/data/result/2_processing_via_vrt/2616500_1261000_colorized.laz"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
time pdal pipeline /data/result/2_processing_via_vrt/colorizing_pipeline.json

real    27m59.195s
user    27m55.134s
sys 0m0.510s
```

The time of processing with VRT might seem very long. But in the other approach shown, I hide the time it needs to match ortho photo and LAZ tiles. So it might catch up a little.

Why is using VRT for colorization in PDAL is so much slower than using the same VRT for visualization in e.g. QGIS?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: This is just a guess, but I think that pdal is not able to treat a vrt as a set of images. It treats it as one big image and reads all tiles instead of opening only the ones that intersect the las bbox.

Comment: "pdal is not able to treat a vrt as a set of images. It treats it as one big image and reads all tiles instead of opening only the ones that intersect the las bbox"

Correct. Patches welcome to change this behavior.